# Python: Copy content from one word document to another word document and keeping format?

Tags: python, ms-word

As the title says I would like to know if there is any module that will allow me to parse content from one Microsoft word document to another via python and keeping the format.

I want to read table data and transfer it to another table in another document.

[image]

Both doc A and B exist. I just want to be able to walk through the cells in both docs (not necessarily at the same time) and copy content without having to worry about if the text is formatted (font, italic, bold) or contains bullets.

I'm asking for python since it's my favorite language...

Comment: you can use python-docx ! https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx

Comment: are you talking about Microsoft Word? Then use the tag ms-word instead. I was deeply confused by your question and your tags, until I realized.

Comment: @Kasra do you have an example code?

Comment: @MariusSiuram that is now updated

Answer (score 3):

Following Kasra advice to use python-docx :

Rough example code.

Query document for table:

```
from docx import *

document = opendocx('xxxzzz.docx')
table = document.xpath('/w:document/w:body/w:tbl', namespaces=nsprefixes)[0]
```

Writing to another document:

```
output = opendocx('yyywwww.docx')
body = output.xpath('/w:document/w:body', namespaces=nsprefixes)[0]

body.append(table)

output.save('new-file-name.docx')
```

Comment: where is `nsprefixes` defined?

Comment: Is the answer to my comment obvious since I don't get a response?