# Copy table from one word document to another

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I ran

```
Python Version: 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016,  11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Pandas Version: 0.18.1
IPython Version: 4.2.0
```

and installed python-docx with

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-docx=0.8.6
```

I have a docx file with some tables in it and I would like either to

1) Copy some tables from the document to a new one, or

2) Remove some tables from the document,

lets say the first table, for 1) or 2).

For 1) I tried using this post here ([Python: Copy content from one word document to another word document and keeping format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638082/python-copy-content-from-one-word-document-to-another-word-document-and-keeping))
but I get an

```
name 'opendocx' is not defined
```

error on the line

```
document = opendocx('xxxzzz.docx')
```

and if I replace 
   opendocx
with 
    Document
I get an

```
'Document' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

error.

I guess opendocx is used on an earlier version or something, so I cannot solve the issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That post refers to a prior version of `python-docx`, before it was rewritten to be object-oriented.

The documentation for `python-docx` is here:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

You can't delete tables (yet), and you can't copy a whole object like a table either, so you would want to read the table from one document and reproduce it in the other, starting with `document.add_table()`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know about the documentation but I would like to copy the table as it is, so that all the content and formatting, style, row-columns dimensions etc are preserved. Any suggestions on how can this be done?